# Plural or singular with respectively

Tags: grammatical-number

1. **Apple** of sort X and **apple** of sort Y are in **basket** 1 and 2, respectively.
2. **Apples** of sort X and of sort Y are in **basket** 1 and 2, respectively.
3. **Apple** of sort X and **apple** of sort Y are in **baskets** 1 and 2, respectively.
4. **Apples** of sort X and of sort Y are in **baskets** 1 and 2, respectively.

Which of the options is correct? If possible, please add a short explanation. But I am happy for any opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that option 4 is the right answer. It uses both apples and baskets in plural because both have more than one.

But I am not completely sure, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I will wait a bit more before I accept the answer, see if more people can confirm that this is right